# Two DHCP bindings

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, windows-server-2008-r2

Please help me resolve very stupid question:

Here is situation:
OS: **2008 R2, DHCP service, 2 NICs**

So, the main goal is to make two scope on DHCP service, each of scope will link to each of NIC.

Any ideas ? O_o

Thanks !

PS Don't ask to reinstall onto Linux,FreeBSD :)

Comment: PS, most of us are professional enough that we don't make useless recomendations like installing a different operating system.

Answer (score 4):

Scopes aren't specific to the NIC AFAIK, but If each NIC is connected to a different VLAN or subnet then DHCP will allocate addresses to each VLAN or subnet from the appropriate Scope.

Comment: Additionally, you don't need 2 NICs if your router/L3 switch between the subnets can act as a DHCP relay agent.  The relay agent stamps the DHCP request with the originating subnet so the DHCP server knows which scope to pull the address from.

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign scopes to particular NICs. An IP will always be pulled from the pool that is within the subnet requesting the IP.

For example. Say your server is connected to 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x.
You setup 2 scopes, one for each subnet; say 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.99 and 192.168.2.50 to 192.168.2.99

When a client from the 1.x network requests and IP it will get an address from the scope where IPs are in the 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.99 range. The same idea applies for the second subnet.

Also, if you setup a third scope, say 192.168.3.50 to 192.168.3.99; and a DHCP Relay agent who has a NIC connected to a 192.168.3.x network can then forward those requests to the server.